# meteor-angular ui.router behaving strange

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I'm working through the meteor-angular tutorial for angular 1 and am having some issue with the routes.js file.  For some reason this displays my files appropriately, but when I add the appropriate path from the root in templateUrl (client/parties/views/parties-list.html) the file does not display. Can someone help me understand why this is happening.  All the docs say that the templateUrl path is absolute.  Thanks.

> > client/routes.js

```
angular.module('socially').config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
  .state('parties', {
    url: '/parties',
    templateUrl: 'parties-list.html',
    controller: 'PartiesListCtrl'
  })
  .state('partyDetails', {
    url: '/parties/:partyId',
    templateUrl: 'party-details.html',
    controller: 'PartyDetailsCtrl'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/parties");
});
```

> > client/parties/views/parties-list.html

```
<form>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input ng-model="newParty.name">
  <label>Description</label>
  <input ng-model="newParty.description">
  <button ng-click="parties.push(newParty)">Add</button>
  <button ng-click="removeAll()">Remove All</button>
</form>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="party in parties">
    <a href="/parties/{{party._id}}">{{party.name}}</a>
    <p>{{party.description}}</p>
    <button ng-click="removeParty(party)">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Got any 404 errors for the template files? If so, that should show you what's wrong with the path

Comment: Hey Phil.  Negative on the 404 errors.  It's a bizarre issue.  I've tried restarting the server, and even rebooting the computer.  For some reason the router.js only routes to the initial path that had the parties-list.html file.  Although, I've moved the file into the public/parties/views directory.

Answer (score 0):

> client/parties/views/parties-list.html

I changed the following line of code from:

```
<button ng-click="parties.push(newParty)">Add</button>
```

to

```
<button ng-click="parties.save(newParty)">Add</button>
```

and the path became absolute... It had something to do with the controller being bypassed and directly accessing the mongo collection that made the path absolute.  Not sure why/how this is the case, though.